# PHP MVC добавить свой класс

Tags: php, ооп, классы, mvc

я использую MVC модель для реализации тестового задания.

Задание в двух словах такое, есть поле с добавлением продукта, и в зависимости от продукта (как я понял) подключается нужный класс.
Так же мне объяснили что нужен абстрактный класс продукта, а все остальные продукты его расширяют и дополняют.

Мои данные из формы, при заполнении, улетают в Контроллер, а тот подтягивает Model, которая добавляет в в базу запись.
Вопрос такой, как бы мне сперва создать этот абстрактный класс (вернее привеньтить) + доп. классы продуктов, и реализовать это всё в моделе или контроллере ?

Answer (score 0):

Ну абстрактный класс на то и абстрактный, что вы вносите в него базовую реадизацию.

```
abstract class Product {
   abstract protected/private/public functions () {
       //тело всегда пустое
   }

   abstract public function getAnswerOnStackOverflow ($answer) {}
}
```

Любыве классы продуктов будут наследоваться от данного:

```
class ProductIT extends Product {
    public function getAnswerOnStackOverflow ($answer) {
        //any manipulations
        return $anyManipulations;
    }
}
```

---

Абстрактным классом может быть хоть модель, хоть контроллер (модель и контроллер относятся к парадигме MVC, даже ее абревиатуре Model-View-Controller, предаставление своеобразного цикла: (сначала принимаете данные в контроллере, проверяете, вызываете модель и отдаете в нее или же в нужный метод от нее данные, модель производит все манипуляции с бизнес-логикой и возвращает результат, результат проверяется или нет в контроллере на корректность, и в корректном виде отдается в *представлене*, то есть во view, вьюха это уже шаблон)).

Надеюсь это поможет вам с представлением MVC модели приложения.

---

Не в обиду, но это тестовое задание вы завалите, просто из-за незнания как корректно подключить уже даже реализованные классы.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю что Такое абстрактный класс и как он работает, что он делает итд,и что от него можно только наследоваться.

Вы наверное не правильно по вопроса.
Меня интересует как подключить его в MVC - я только начал его изучать.
И на примерах Это обычно - Контроллер получил запрос, обработал, толи сразу Views вывел то ли Пропустил через модель с Логикой и вернул.
Но никто не говорит как закинуть туда свой Класс. Пример хотя бы на словах там : Создай абстрактный класс, потом как получишь запрос для Модели, расширяй абстрактный класс реализуй логику

Comment: Вы сами не понмаете своего вопроса, как понять, подключить абстрактный класс, или привентить? Если класс, будь то абстрактный, является составляющей парадигмы MVC, по факту структура приложения. Им нужно там пользоваться, а не прикручивать как вы выражаетесь, а пользоваться им там можно, как я указал, вот и *привинтите*, а если вас интересует конкретное подключение класса, то такой знаток и так должен это знать, коль с абстрактными классами у вас все на ура.

Comment: Вы зря горячитесь. Не думал вас задеть. Благодарю.